# How to get local machine ip using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to get local machine ip using python script. And try to open a file from another machine using machine ip. how to get.

Comment: If you could open the files of another machine only using an IP address, Everyone on the Internet would get hacked constantly forever.

Comment: @Kevin: And we wouldn't call it hacking, but strolling...